# how to create model instance with circular foreign key that cannot be null

Tags: django, foreign-keys, django-2.2

In my django app I have two Model in a one-to-many relationship: `Term` and `TermName` (`Term` has many `TermName`). I want to keep track in `Term` of a particular `TermName` instance, say `TermName` models are name alias or the related `Term` model, but one of them is the "reference" name alias. For this I have added a one-to-one relation between the two Models. Here is the code:

```
class TermName(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    term = models.ForeignKey(
        'Term', 
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )

class Term(models.Model):
    ref_termname = models.OneToOneField(
        TermName, 
        on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING,
        related_name = 'reference_of_term',
    )
```

Problem is if I create a new `Term` instance, django complains that `ref_termname` cannot be null. However sames goes if I want to create the "reference" `TermName` beforehands; it now complains about `term` being null ...

My workaround is to let `ref_termname` be null (i.e. use `null=True` field option). But for my model design I would like to make it not nullable. Can this be possible?

thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

What if you move your `OneToOneField` to your `TermName` model? I'm thinking you could model this as follows:

```py
class TermName(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    term = models.ForeignKey(
        'Term', 
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    reference_of_term = models.OneToOneField(
        TermName, 
        on_delete=models.PROTECT,
        related_name = 'ref_termname',
    )

class Term(models.Model):
    pass
```

Now you should be able to create `Term`'s instances first and then create `TermName`s that point to a `Term`. The only disadvantage is that `Term`s are not forced to have a `TermName`.